# How can I make this formula simple to run my google worksheet faster?

Tags: google-sheets

I have like 10000 rows of data in google sheets and I am trying to run and sort based on dates using this formula. pls see attached pic.

It takes so long (high loading time) to return results. Any idea on how I can simplify the formula?
Any thought is appreciated! thanks.

I am using this formula:

`=iferror(Index($A$2:$D$20000, SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$20000<=$F$2)*($B$2:$B$20000>=$E$2), MATCH(ROW($A$2:$A$20000), ROW($A$2:$A$20000)), ""), ROW(D2291)), COLUMN(D2291)), "No info")`

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an attached picture?

Comment: Without looking at any data, if you have 10,000 rows of data then don't use a data range that allows for 20,000 rows of data.

Comment: `Row(D2291)` - that just going to return a value of 2291, so is `ROW` necessary? Ditto `COLUMN(D2291)` will return 4.

Answer (score 0):

To speed it up, downsize the row count. The data of 20,000 rows should be the size of your data.

**Helper column**

Introduce a helper column that pre-calculates. It will reduce the computation load and, more importantly, make the primary formula easier to maintain.

```
=IF(AND($B2<=$F$2, $B2>=$E$2), 1, "")
```

The formula in (for example) `column Z` gives the matching rows a value of `1`.

For instance, you can do the following:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$20000, MATCH(1, $Z$2:$Z$20000, 0), COLUMN(D2291)), "No info")
```

The revised formula will use the `MATCH` function to find the first row in your helper column, which indicates a match (`1`), and then it picks up the corresponding value from your primary data range. `IFERROR` returns `"No info"` if no match is found.

**Tl;dr**

Implement a helper **VLOOKUP** column for the main formula to search for related information by row.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en